# Adding visualforce page via Page Layout vs Edit Object menu

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, edit

When I attempt to add a visual force to my Account layout page I've been able to do this 1 of 2 ways. This first is to go to an `Account view` and click `settings -> Edit object` and put the visual force page on the related tab or details tab in the new lightning interface.

The second is to edit the `page layout` in the `Object Manager` to put the visualforce page on the layout although this seems to only show on the Details tab. Can someone clarify what both of these methods are doing? E.g is edit object editing all the layouts for all users that have access to the object?

Little bit confused on this and what best practice should be.

Look forward to some clarification thanks!

Comment: Both methods do the same functionality i.e. adding a custom visualforce page to related list of that Object. However editing any specific layout will affect only those users who have access to that layout.

Answer (score 0):

When you go `settings -> Edit object -> Edit and Tab` and put the VF on related tab then it will replace the native page with your ustom Visualforce page.

When you put your page in page layout then it will be displayed as inline Visualforce page in standard page. The standra dpage will not be changed your page is just a part of this standard page

Comment: So the only way to have the VF page on the related tab is to edit the object NOT edit the layout which puts it on the details tab. I do not want all users to see the VF page just select users to see it in the related tab. Will edit object show the VF page on all users pages?

Comment: @FreddieCrouch yes edit object show the VF page on all users pages.